# Show that $ \int_0^1{x^m(1-x)^n}dx = \int_0^1{x^n(1-x)^m}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If m and n are positive integers, show that
$$ \int_0^1{x^m(1-x)^n}dx = \int_0^1{x^n(1-x)^m}dx $$
The only solution I was able to find was the following:
Using $u=1-x$, $du/dx=-1$ we can change the left side to
$$ -\int_1^0{(1-u)^mu^n}du $$
Which is basically the same thing as
$$ -\int_1^0{x^n(1-x)^m}dx $$
Which gives us
$$ -\int_1^0{x^n(1-x)^m}dx = \int_0^1{x^n(1-x)^m}dx $$
$$ 0 = \int_0^1{x^n(1-x)^m}dx + \int_1^0{x^n(1-x)^m}dx $$
Which due to additivity becomes
$$ 0 = \int_1^1{x^n(1-x)^m}dx $$
Is this correct, and is there another way to prove this by changing either side of the equality so that both sides match?

Comment: I do think mirroring the integrand around $x = 1/2$ is the best way to do it, but going through the actual substitution the hard way seems a bit unintuitive.

Comment: You’re fine right up to the line after "Which gives us...” At that point, you’re done.

Comment: You are evaluting the Beta function $B(m+1,n+1)$.  And the transformation $x\to 1-x$ does indeed reveal that $B(x,y)=B(y,x)$.

Comment: It is always true that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = -\int_b^a f(x) dx$, so you can simply apply this to conclude that $-\int_1^0x^n(1-x)^m dx = \int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^m dx$.

Comment: Am I the only one confused by the $xd$ in the integral?

Comment: @Math1000 I’m sure that’s just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u:=1-x \Rightarrow x=1-u \:\:\& \:\: \mbox{d}x=-\mbox{d}u$$

$$\Downarrow$$

$$ \int_0^1{x^m(1-x)^n}\mbox{d}x = -\int_1^0 (1-u)^mu^n\mbox{d}u = \int_0^1 (1-u)^mu^n\mbox{d}u = \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]{\int_0^1 (1-x)^mx^n\mbox{d}x}$$

Comment: I thought so, but I couldn't find the identity of that middle equality.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $$\int_{a}^b f(x) dx= \int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$$
Applying this in the given integral,
$$\int _0^1 x^m(1-x)^n dx=\int_0^1 (1-x)^mx^ndx$$

Comment: Huh. Never seen that before.

Comment: You can try to prove it and then use it in generality, it's a very useful property as you can see.